# Error: Syntax Error. Missing '=' for formula

Tags: formula, workflow, workflowrule

Please help . I am receiving a syntax error for this formula. Tried many ways. Not able to figure out. I am sure i must be doing something silly.

Error: Syntax error. Missing '='

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK([ServiceAppointment].WorkTypeId)),
    CONTAINS( "Easy|Hard", TEXT([ServiceAppointment].WorkType.Name)),
    ISPICKVAL([ServiceAppointment].Status, "Scheduled"),
    NOT($User.Data_Migration_User__c ),
    NOT(ISBLANK([ServiceAppointment].ContactId ))
)
```

Comment: Is Data_Migration_User__c a boolean? if not use = to compare with some value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ObjectName]` syntax applies for Process builder formulas and according to the tags on your question, you are trying to build a workflow rule.

Assuming that the workflow rule is being executed from `ServiceAppointment` object, then you can reference the merged fields directly in the formula like this:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(WorkTypeId)),
    CONTAINS( "Easy|Hard", TEXT(WorkType.Name)),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Scheduled"),
    NOT($User.Data_Migration_User__c ),
    NOT(ISBLANK(ContactId ))
)
```

Hope this helps